# Dynamically linked library under iOS AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, dynamic-library

I want to use dynamically linked libraries in my iOs app. My problem is that I read that I can use only static libraries. I searched about that on official Apple web side but I cant find anything about this. Can someone point me the link to official Apple information that says I cant use dynamically linked library in my iOS project?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484989/ios-6-1-dynamic-library-build-and-link

Answer (score 5):

Apple only allows dynamically linked libraries in Mac apps, currently they are disallowed on the iOS app store.

edit: Scroll to the bottom here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH6-SW3
to see Apple's official stance.