# Native code deployment on iOS

Tags: ios, deployment, runtime, dynamic-linking, native-code

IIRC runtime compilation and linkage to JIT-ed native code is not allowed on iOS. I was wondering does it affect native code that was not compiled on the client machine but a remote build server and deployed and linked to internally. Is the problem "native code generated on the fly" or "native code that has not passed Apple's review process"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there's no correct way to dynamic linking in iOS - it's prohibited by Apple.

Also look here please: [Can you build dynamic libraries for iOS and load them at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime)

Comment: What about... hmmm... jailbroken devices?

Comment: Sorrry, I cant' say anything about jailbroken devices - I always write for Appstore publishing only. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484989/ios-6-1-dynamic-library-build-and-link