# iphone-How to send the SMS without navigating message window in ios [not duplicated]

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to send the SMS on button click automatically without navigating message composer in iOS Please anyone help me.
My scenario is

1.I want to send the verification code to user While registering.

I import and used CTMessageCenter.h file but It gives error like NSObject.h file is not found.please help me to solve this problem .I stuck from so many days.

Comment: in ios no way to send messsage without composer , you can send message to your own server and then send message from your server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13063499/1405008 try this

Comment: @sabeer pls give me the procedure to your solution

Comment: @Anupama just send your message to your own server and then your server will send a message to device 
ex: may use any web api .net or php and then send your message to server

Comment: @CoolMonster thank you for solution but i am not looking for this

Comment: Yes, like sabeer said u can send a request or notification to your server and and make ur server send messages... Apple doesn't allow us to send messages with just one click because one can send any number of messages without users knowledge. This is one reason apple has restricted that.

Answer (score 1):

Only one solution is that We used the API Service to send the SMS Like other App.If we used the private frameworks the App is definitely rejected from App store

Answer (score 0):

Take iOS 7 runtime headers from https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers .
They look a little bit different from yours, i.e. there is no import of `NSObject.h` in `CTMessageCenter.h` and there is no file `CDStructure.h`. These runtime headers are generated by *RuntimeBrowser* instead of *Class-dump*.

In my case, the compiler errors went away.

EDIT:
But it seems there is an other problem with `sendSMSWithText:serviceCenter:toAddress:` from `CTMessageCenter` under iOS 7, see [Sending SMS using CTMessageCenter (iOS 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175209/sending-sms-using-ctmessagecenter-ios-7) .