# Send background SMS without interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, iphone-privateapi

I want to send a background SMS in iOS 7, and i dont want user to have to interact with any front end view. How can i do this ?
I will use this application for myself (no app store), so private api allowed .

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653828/hacking-into-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

It might give you ideas do achieve it in unorthodox ways. But there is no answer to that question yet.

Answer (score -1):

With MFMessageComposerViewController it is not possible to send without user interaction. You have to take SMS gateway and implement your own way of sending SMS, than only it is possible. Like you have to create webservice and accept parameters from iPhone like phonenumber and message and than send SMS using SMS gateway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: have you implemented like this in your app?? Please let me know if you have done like this as I need to implement same in my iOS app. Thank you.