# How to Send SMS using CTMessageCenter or any approch Without composer view controller ( iOS 7 )

Tags: xcode, ios7, sms, ios7.1

i want send a message in background without composer view controller,i have Tried to bellow this code

```
BOOL success =  [[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] sendSMSWithText:@"XYZ"   serviceCenter:nil toAddress:@"+9199007300"];

    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Message Sent = %d",success);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Message not sent   = %d",success);
    }
```

This code always prints "Message not sent  = 0".Please Can anyone help me ?

Comment: In order to use this API on iOS 7 and above you need to add another entitlement with bool value set to true - com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872553/send-programmatically-sms-on-jailbreak-device/20425853#20425853