# how to use ldid to add entitlements in deb file?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

now i am using the theos make a jailbreak application . and i want to make the application send sms without user interaction. so i refer to this [send sms in program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872553/send-programmatically-sms-on-jailbreak-device)

it says:

> In order to use this API on iOS 7 and above you need to add another
> entitlement with bool value set to true -
> com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get.

in the referce said i had to use ldid to sign the ipa , but in theos , there only will make a deb file , and how to make the deb file sign with the entitlements by ldid , thanks

Comment: `deb` is an archive. You need to sign the binary before it gets packed up.

Comment: @Siguza hi , i am new to jailbreak developement , can you explain how to do it more specificly? thanks so much

Comment: A quick google search turns up [this](https://github.com/theos/theos/issues/40). Seems all you have to do is set the environment variable `TARGET_CODESIGN_FLAGS` to something like `-S/path/to/entitlements.plist` before invoking theos (or put it in your Makefile or whatever, I have honestly no idea what theos projects look like).

Comment: for all @Siguza 's answer is right for the answer , do as his words :)